# Image From Server Not Showing On Page Codeigniter

Tags: image, codeigniter

I've got this index page in Codeigniter:

```
            <?php
        if(!isset($posts)){
            ?>
            <p> There Are Currently No Posts On This SIte.</p>
            <?php 
        } else { 
            foreach ($posts as $row){

                ?>


            <img src="<?echo base_url().'uploads/'.$row['image_path'];?>">
        <?

            }
?>
                <p> There Are Posts On This SIte.</p>
                <?php
}?>
```

And when I load the page, I get this:

[image: Photo of web page]

Looking at the source, I can see the IMG HTML tag is sourced propely, **VIA THE SERVER**, to the file:

[image: Source Code]

Can you please explain why the picture is not showing?

A couple note:

`$image_path` is the picture's name inside the `uploads` folder.

`Base_url()` is configured correctly in the `config.php` file.

**EDIT:** The Apache log throws a 20024 error: The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters..... Yet I can't seem to see any problems with the path....

Comment: What happens when you open the image link in the browser?

Comment: That's a pretty strong indication that the image doesn't exist at that location, then. Are you 100000% sure you have the correct path?

Comment: Yep. I've got a script that uploads it, resizes it, and puts it in that exact folder.

Comment: What kind of server is this? If it's a Linux server, what are the uploaded file's permissions

Comment: It's XAMPP (Apache) Running on a Windows machine.

Comment: What does the error log say? It should tell you what local path it is trying to access

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44063/discussion-between-wideblade-and-pekka-)

Comment: Notice the edit @Pekka웃

Comment: Does it say what path was given?

Comment: Yeah, but it's irrelevent - the path that's logged is one I've changed about 4 revisions ago - it's not the same one as is in the code. now. The one in the code now throws a 404, but for some reason is not logged in the error.log file...

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell, but if I see right your Base_url() is missing something, my bet is the config is incorrect, Usally it's `http://localhost:3000/firstapp...`not`http://localhost/firstapp`

Comment: Nope - That's not it. The path is shown properly. I'm starting to think my server won't display images from the root folder for some obscure configuration reason. Any thoughts?